# Javascript Map and Filter on two array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have one array like:

```
arr = ['AD','CI','AI']
```

and I have one object like

```
{ 
  "AD": "Mailing Address",
  "CI": "Additional Interest",
  "HO": "Homeowners",
  "AI": "Additional Interest"
}
```

Here the object contains the key value pair and form the array key how to compare that key into the object and get the value of that key.
  How to get the value of array key from the object ?

Comment: Was the answer helpful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Array.forEach()` to loop over the array and get the value from the object:

```js
var arr = ['AD','CI','AI'];
var obj = {"AD": "Mailing Address","CI": "Additional Interest","HO":"Homeowners","AI": "Additional Interest"};
arr.forEach(key => console.log(obj[key]));
```

If you want to use that value further inside the loop then make it multi-line like:

```js
var arr = ['AD','CI','AI'];
var obj = {"AD": "Mailing Address","CI": "Additional Interest","HO":"Homeowners","AI": "Additional Interest"};
arr.forEach((key) => {
  //some processing here
  console.log(obj[key]);
});
```

Use `map()` to get the array of those values:

```js
var arr = ['AD','CI','AI'];
var obj = {"AD": "Mailing Address","CI": "Additional Interest","HO":"Homeowners","AI": "Additional Interest"};
var res = arr.map((key) => obj[key]);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

This one-liner will give you an array `result` containing the values from the object.

`let result = arr.map(a=>obj[a]);`

Answer (score 1):

is the array needed in your case? if you just want the values of the object you can do this:

```
const obj = { 
  "AD": "Mailing Address",
  "CI": "Additional Interest",
  "HO": "Homeowners",
  "AI": "Additional Interest"
};

Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => console.log(`${key}: ${value}`));
```

or

```
const obj = { 
  "AD": "Mailing Address",
  "CI": "Additional Interest",
  "HO": "Homeowners",
  "AI": "Additional Interest"
};

Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => console.log(`${obj[key]}`));
```

Hopefully that is helpful!